# How to get the url of the page from which a Post request was triggered?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

Lets say that I am no https://localhost/My-cool-page?color=blue&brand=ferrari
and from that page I make a post request to my backend
https://localhost/api/getCars

how do I from the http request find out that the request came from the page
https://localhost/My-cool-page?color=blue&brand=ferrari

and not localhost as the origin of the httprequest states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the referer. You can do this

```
string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
```